# How to save a tuple itens in two fields in django?

Tags: django-models, django-forms

In django, i have a project with these model:

```
class Colorify(models.Model):
    color_code = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    color_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
```

The user filled in the color_code and color_name in two separate fields, which sometimes resulted in filling errors and now, I am creating a field with choices so that the user can select a color, and the code will be filled in automatically. However, without altering the database.
Something like this:

```
class Colorify(models.Model):
    COLOR = (
        ('149', 'Blue'),
        ('133', 'Red'),
        ('522', 'Black'),
    )
    color_select = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        choices=COLOR,
    )
    code = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    color = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
```

I'm unsure if it's possible to save in forms.py based on the color the user chooses from the tuple, so that 'colorify.code' receives the tuple's code, and 'colorify.color' receives the respective color name. However, I'm not certain about how the save() method would look like.

Or if there is a simpler way to address this issue without altering the database.

I envisioned something along these lines:

`

```
def save(self):
    colorify.name = colorify.color_select.value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`COLOR = (('149', 'Blue'),('133', 'Red'),('522', 'Black'),)`** This tupel of tupel is actually items of python dictionary so, you can convert it in a dictionary using **`dict()`**

##### models.py

```py
class Colorify(models.Model):
    COLOR_CHOICES = [
        ('149', 'Blue'),
        ('133', 'Red'),
        ('522', 'Black'),
    ]

    color_select = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        choices=COLOR_CHOICES,
    )
    code = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    color = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Get the selected color tuple
        selected_color = dict(self.COLOR_CHOICES).get(self.color_select)
        # print(self.color_select,selected_color)
        if selected_color:
            # Update the 'code' and 'color' fields based on the selected color
            self.code, self.color =self.color_select, selected_color

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

#### Preview

[image]